# Best data structure to find price difference between two time frames

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures

I am working on a project where my task is to find the % price change given 2 time frames for 100+ stocks in an efficient way.

The time frames are pre defined and can only be 5 mins, 10 mins, 30 mins, 1 hour, 4 hour, 12 hour, 24 hours. 
Given a time frame, I need a way to efficiently figure out the % price change of all the stocks that I am tracking.

As per the current implementation, I am getting price data for those stocks every second and dumping the data to a price table.

I have another cron job which updates the % change of the stock based on the values in the price table every few seconds.

The solution is kind of in working state but its not efficient. Is there any data structure/ algorithm that I can use to find the % change efficiently?

Comment: why do you think it is not efficient? if I understand it correctly, calculating price difference of a stock is just a subtraction of two items in price table, updating hundreds of stocks in a second should be an easy job for modern cpu.

Comment: Which part is not efficient? Second-by-second price data for 100 stocks over a 24-hour period will occupy perhaps 100 megabytes of memory, and lookup would be nearly instantaneous. And there are APIs available that should easily allow you to update 100 stocks every second. You'll have to give us more detail if you want anything like a reasonable answer here. It's unlikely that your method that uses `cron` jobs to write to tables and update second-by-second price changes is going to scale well.